# Remove a substr from string items in a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, strip

```
list = [ 'u'adc', 'u'toto', 'u'tomato', ...]
```

What I want is to end up with a list of the kind:
    list2 = [ 'adc', 'toto', 'tomato'... ]

Can you please tell me how to do that without using regex?
I'm trying:

```
for item in list:
            list.extend(str(item).replace("u'",''))
            list.remove(item)
```

but this ends up giving something of the form [ 'a', 'd', 'd', 'm'...]

In the list I may have an arbitrary number of strings.

Comment: I assume your using Python 2?

Comment: ThIs that first line of code _really_ your actual data? It is invalid syntax.

Comment: Also, where exactly are you getting that list from? A list of that form raises a syntax error in _both_ Python versions.

Comment: The quotes are not part of the data. They are only there because python prints them. If you look at the first  item in the list it will be three bytes long, not 5 or 6. In other words, assuming your data is an actual list, there is nothing you can remove

Comment: if you print the list, it is going to look like this [ 'u'adc', 'u'toto', 'u'tomato', ...] without the ... part of course, it is not a syntax error in the real code, it's just not cutting what is needed. And again, if you apply my algorithm it returns a list full of bunch of letters instead of whole words without the 'part.

Comment: @KDX2 if `'u'adc'` is your item, it is obviously syntax error because it have three quotes! that is what @BryanOakley meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can encode it to "utf-8" like this:

```
list_a=[ u'adc', u'toto', u'tomato']
list_b=list()
for i in list_a:
    list_b.append(i.encode("utf-8"))
list_b
```

output:

```
['adc', 'toto', 'tomato']
```

Or you can use str function：

```
list_c = list()
for i in list_a:
    list_c.append(str(i))
list_c
```

Output:

```
['adc', 'toto', 'tomato']
```

Comment: It is a utf8 encoding issue. I usually face this when working with json data

Comment: Thank you, I am checking it now. If it works I'll definitely mark your answer, as it is very detailed. 1moment

Comment: Why not use a comprehension?

Comment: @KDX2, I am writing the same above solution using Map/Lambda function. As it is single line code. Please find it in post as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use "u\'"

For example:

```
l = [ "u'adc", "u'toto", "u'tomato"]
for item in l:
    print(item.replace("u\'", ""))
```

Will output:

```
adc
toto
tomato
```

Comment: Oh, God, this also works... I was thinking to try with the backslash but unfortunately didn't :D Thank you all guys, you all helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I verified your question but it says the syntax problem, which means that the way you are declaring the string in the list is not proper. In which case, I have corrected that at line #2.

```
In [1]: list = [ 'u'adc', 'u'toto', 'u'tomato']
  File "<ipython-input-1-2c6e581e868e>", line 1
    list = [ 'u'adc', 'u'toto', 'u'tomato']
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [2]: list = [ u'adc', u'toto', u'tomato']

In [3]: list = [ str(item) for item in list ]

In [4]: list
Out[4]: ['adc', 'toto', 'tomato']

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for item in list:
    for x in range(0, len(item)):
        if item[x] == 'u':
            item[x] = ''
```

This takes all instances in the list, and checks for the string 'u'. If 'u' is found, than the code replaces it with a blank string, essentially deleting it. Some more code could allow this to check for combinations of letters ('abc', etc.).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution-1**

```
input_list = [ u'adc', u'toto', u'tomato']
output_list=map(lambda x:str(x),input_list )
print output_list
```

And Output Look like:

```
 ['adc', 'toto', 'tomato']
```

**Solution-2**

```
input_list = [ u'adc', u'toto', u'tomato']
output_list=map(lambda x:x.encode("utf-8"),input_list )
print output_list
```

And Output Look like:

```
 ['adc', 'toto', 'tomato']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is nothing but a **json**! You the dump each item in the list(which is a json!) to get the desired output!

Since your output comes with quotes - you need to strip(beginning and trailing) them!

```
import json
list = [ u'adc', u'toto', u'tomato']
print [json.dumps(i).strip('\"') for i in list]
```

Output:

```
['adc', 'toto', 'tomato']
```

Hope it helps!